# process.env variables undefined React App - Not using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a custom React app, and it's **not** using `create-react-app`.  Problem is I can use `dotenv` and environment variables lo**c**ally via `.env` file but when in production `process.env` is `undefined` entirely.

I don't know how to get it working.  I've added the environment variables to my server in Google Cloud but process.env itself is not even defined, the same code that worked locally does not work on a virtual prod server.

So for example something like this works locally but not in production:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  response = await request.post(process.env.GRAPHQ_LOCAL).send(query);
} else {
  response = await request.post(process.env.GRAPHQL_PROD).send(query);
}
```

Comment: By "in production" do you mean when you serve the built HTML/CSS/JS? They're just static files, they have no access to the env vars on whatever's serving them. Those values need to be set at *build* time, or you need to have some runtime configuration (I prefer the latter, I wrote more about why and how to do it [here](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Your project starter file add dotenv init...

if you install this package, should be work

```
require('dotenv').config()
```